# How to render checkbox as checked from localstorage data

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am new to Sencha and was am looking for help in setting a checkbox to checked when retrieving data from local storage. I have a basic form that saves data with no problems, and can even load the retrieved data back into the form when i want to edit. However, the checkboxes do not appear as checked and I was hoping someone could help me out or explain how i would accomplish this.
The following code snippet is activated when the edit button is pressed, slides in the form page and populates the data from local storage into the form;

```
    activateNewEvent: function(record) {
        var newEvent = this.getNewEvent();
        newEvent.setRecord(record);
//      console.log(record);
        Ext.Object.each(record.data, function(key,value) {
            if(value != 'false') {
//              record.set('checked', true);
//              key.checked(true);
            }
        });
        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(newEvent, this.left);
    },
```

My console shows all the form data and the checkbox data, so the info is being saved correctly, but I am struggling to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

It's been over a year since I worked with something like this but I think you want to use setValue(true) on the checkbox object. I don't know if changing the underlying record after rendering will check the box.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this does not check the box